# Crontab not running files

Tags: server, 20.04, php, cron

I've been repairing a problem in my crontab, it ran all the files without any problem but suddenly it stopped running, it shows in the syslog that the file was executed but I did a test php that built a txt and writing that something inside
I put it in cron and it shows in the syslog executed but it didn't open the php file, I noticed this in all the other files that have it.

Syslog:

```
Oct  1 08:32:53 cpro45509 crontab[29419]: (www-data) LIST (www-data)
Oct  1 08:33:01 cpro45509 CRON[29432]: (www-data) CMD (/usr/bin/php /home/kdl/site/lab/NewLeaflet/php/progmuc.php  1624001010 2 2040001 1 2)
Oct  1 08:33:01 cpro45509 CRON[29431]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Crontab:

```
28 08 *  *  *  /usr/bin/php /home/kdl/site/lab/NewLeaflet/php/progmuc.php 1624001010 1 2040001 1 2
33 08 *  *  *  /usr/bin/php /home/kdl/site/lab/NewLeaflet/php/progmuc.php  1624001010 2 2040001 1 2
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  $fp = fopen("testeee.txt", "a");
    // Escreve "exemplo de escrita" no bloco1.txt
    $escreve = fwrite($fp, "Funcionou");
    // Fecha o arquivo
    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Please remove the images and copy/paste the text into the question.

Comment: Ready change made

Comment: Your output clearly shows that your cronjob is generating an error. Edit your cron job to redirect that error message to a file so you can read it (Redirection example: `33 08 * * * cmd  >> /some/log/file 2>&1`)